# Replace string if the string is not part of a larger string using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, regex, string, replace

I'm trying to write a function which would Uppercase some words in a `textarea` but I'm having trouble, as these words could be part of other words and I only want to uppercase them when they are standing alone.

E.g.: I want to uppercase `OR` but only when not in a word like `befORe`. These words can however be written in a multitude of ways, like at the start of a line, between one or more `whitespace` characters or in something like this: `(somethingsomething)OR(somethingelse)` and probably even more, depending on the way other people write their query code.

I had the idea of working with `regex`, but I'm not skilled enough to work out every possibility of writing these words.

I have no way of changing the `textarea` to other, better plugins or editors as it's already part of a functioning script.

Any helpful idea would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: One additional question

I got really helpful answers to my question, Thank you everyone. I do have an additional question though. What if, other then checking that it's not part of a word, I also want to check that it's not preceded or followed by a `.` period. I tried adding `(?!\.)` at the beginning of it, but that doesN't work at all. Is there a way to check for that as well?

//EDIT: Never mind, I figured it out. it's \b(?!\.)something(?!\.)\b for the check at the start and end of the word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? ( °_• )

```
var txt="or some text or before (.)or(.) anywhere Or";

console.log(txt.replace(/\bor\b/gi,"OR"));     

// "OR some text OR before (.)OR(.) anywhere OR"
```

Comment: I will try this out, but while I do so, may I ask for some clarification what `\b` is? Or in general what this line itself does?

Answer (score 2):

Matching on a word boundary `\b` may suit:

```
'foo or bar'.replace(/\bor\b/, 'OR'); // foo OR bar
```

You can also provide a function to replace, so:

```
'foo or bar'.replace(/\b(or)\b/, function(m){return m.toUpperCase()})); // foo OR bar
```

which might be good for cases where you have multiple possible matches:

```
'foo or bar and fum'.replace(/\b(or|and)\b/ig, function(m){return m.toUpperCase()}); // foo OR bar AND fum
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
'(something)or(somethingelse) before or oR Or OR oreos thor'.replace([^\w]([oO][rR])[^\w], 'OR');
```